# Initializing with Character vs char array

Tags: java, autoboxing

This prints **false**

```
List vowelsList=Arrays.asList(new char[]{'a','e','i','o','u'});
System.out.println(vowelsList.contains('a'));//false
```

This prints **true**

```
List vowelsList=Arrays.asList(new Character[]{'a','e','i','o','u'});
System.out.println(vowelsList.contains('a'));//true
```

`char` is autoboxed to `Character` which I had used in char array initailizer..Why am I getting different results!

Comment: Because `char[]` is considered as a single parameter in the `T ... params`, while `Character[]` parameter is considered the array parameter for `T ... params`.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza: that should be an answer.

Comment: Also, you don't need to declare the type while initialising as "Arrays.asList('a','e','i','o','u','A','E','I','O','U');" should also work and also eradicates the confusion, provided you have mentioned the type while declaring the list.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Also print

`vowelsList.size();`

for both, and you'll see the difference ;)

**Spoiler:**

The generic type of the first method is `char[]`, so you'll get a list of size one. It's type is `List<char[]>`. The generic type of your second code is `Character`, so your list will have as many entries as the array. The type is `List<Character>`.

---

To avoid this kind of mistake, don't use raw types! Following code **will not compile**:

```
List<Character> vowelsList = Arrays.asList(new char[]{'a','e','i','o','u'});
```

Following three lines are fine:

```
List<char[]> list1 = Arrays.asList(new char[]{'a','e','i','o','u'}); // size 1
List<Character> list2 = Arrays.asList(new Character[]{'a','e','i','o','u'}); // size 5
List<Character> list3 = Arrays.asList('a','e','i','o','u'); // size 5
```

Answer (score 1):

As @jlordo (+1) said your mistake is in understanding what does your list contain. In first case it contains one element of type `char[]`, so that it does not contain `char` element  `a`. In second case it contains 5 `Character` elements 'a','e','i','o','u', so the result is `true`.